# Rails find by integer property fails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have this query in a GET route:

```
@user = User.where("facebook_id = ?", params[:id].to_i).first
```

`facebook_id` is type `bigint`

and I am feeding it values that I know exist based on printing out all the properties in all my `User` models. The problem is this query only works on some numbers.

It works for these numbers:

```
1095512640500310
10155111451974992
10100608785176432
```

but not for these numbers

```
10154326172258840
10205871322198368
10153714225855256
```

Why does this query work for some numbers but not others?

**UPDATE:**

Here is a screenshot of a different query that prints out `facebook_id` values:

[image]

but this query: `@user = User.find_by_facebook_id(10154326172258840)`

returns `nil` for `@user`

**UPDATE**

I found that there is a discrepency between the value in the DB and the value that rails prints out. If I print out the `facebook_id` for this particular user in PG, I see this:

[image]

The last digit here is `1` while the last digit in the rails print out is `0`.

Why would rails be printing out an incorrect value? Is it rounding for some reason?

Comment: Can you try with `User.find_by_facebook_id(params[:id].to_i)` first and see if those return `nil`?

Comment: you know you nave the same number on both lists right? so you are saying 1/2 the time that number works and the other half it doesn't?  10154326172258840.  Or is it that the first list always works and the second list never works.  There is a big difference to 60% of the tries don't work and 60% of the time the lookup doesn't work even with same values

Comment: @Matt I included a wrong value in the first list. It works 100% of the time for the top numbers, and 0% of the time for the bottom numbers

Comment: @Jeff I tried `@user = User.find_by_facebook_id(10154326172258840)` but user was `nil`

Comment: What happens if you bypass Rails completely and ask the database (via `psql`) to `select id from users where facebook_id = 10154326172258840`?

Comment: @muistooshort nothing happens when I press enter. How do I print out the id? I tried on values that were working in rails and still didn't see anythign

Comment: If it's `nil` then your records don't exist with that `facebook_id` foreign key. Unless you are using the wrong database connection...

Comment: @cbas do the sql command and add `;` after to complete the command

Comment: @Jeff ok I am seeing the same results in psql, no result for some ids, correct results for others. If the value doesn't exist in the DB, how is my rails app printing it out in a different query? Both queries are using the same DB connection

Comment: What exactly is `params[:id]` when it fails unexpectedly? What exactly is the value of `facebook_id` in those cases?

Comment: @muistooshort the value is `10154326172258840`. an integer

Comment: And in the database...

Comment: OK I've made progress - check the update. Seems rails is printing out an incorrect value... why is that?

Comment: As an aside, I'd probably use a `text` column for the `facebook_id`. Just because it looks like an integer doesn't mean it really is one, it is really just an opaque identifier that (currently) just happens to contain digits.

Comment: Show us the output in your development.log when you make the AR query with a number that doesn't work.  Does the SQL in the log match up?